# Speaking urls in sitemap generated by tx_seo

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have a sitemap, generated by tx_seo for an extension "myext".

The sitemap works, but the links generated look like:

```
http://domain.local/detail?tx_myext_pi1[action]=list&tx_myext_pi1[controller]=Read&tx_myext_pi1[uid]=333&cHash=4d4...
```

while they should look like:

```
http://domain.local/detail/title-of-record-333
```

I have already defined an appropriate routing in sites/mysite/config.yaml.

Is there a way to use the routeEnhancers of config.yaml to get readable urls in the sitemap as well?

Of course, I could build a new SitemapDataProvider-Class and create the links there. But this is duplicate code, and might have subtle differences to the solution in config.yaml. So my preferred way would be to use the mechanism defined in config.yaml - but I can't find any hint how that could possibly work.

Here is the configuration I use in config.yaml:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    map:
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435
  MyPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyExt
    plugin: Pi1
    defaultController: 'Mycontroller::list'
    limitToPages: [12345]
    routes:
      - routePath: '/mypath/{question}/{tab}/{theme}'
        _controller: 'Mycontroller::show'
    aspects:
      question:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_question
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      theme:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_theme
        routeFieldName: name
      tab:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '3'
```

Comment: That should work out of the box. Do your routes on the page itself look okay?

Comment: yes, the routes on the page look ok. But they have some more parameters in them like static/route/title-of-record/category/tag.
That works fine.

Comment: Maybe you can share your routes configuration in your question? That might help to provide an answer.

Comment: I have added the routes configuration in my question.

Comment: I've added my answer, feel free to comment on the answer and I'll update it if necessary. Maybe you also want to add your TypoScript configuration for your records sitemap generation to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration currently only configures a single route which expects three arguments:

1. question
2. tab
3. theme

The sitemap generates a link containing only a uid argument.
Therefore there is no route configured that can be used.
You would either need to configure a route for only uid argument.
Or you need to adjust the proper building of the URLs for your sitemap to include the arguments question, tab and theme instead of uid.

So I guess you need proper configuration of your sitemap, following: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Seo/XmlSitemap.html#for-records
There you can configure the url to build for each record, no need to build a custom PHP class.

This is the example taken from docs for completeness in case the link might no longer include the example:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        <sitemapType> {
            sitemaps {
                <unique key> {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        table = news_table
                        sortField = sorting
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        changeFreqField = news_changefreq
                        priorityField = news_priority
                        additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
                        pid = <page id('s) containing news records>
                        recursive = <number of subpage levels taken into account beyond the pid page. (default: 0)>
                        url {
                            pageId = <your detail page id>
                            fieldToParameterMap {
                                uid = tx_extension_pi1[news]
                            }
                            additionalGetParameters {
                                tx_extension_pi1.controller = News
                                tx_extension_pi1.action = detail
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hints.
Actually I had to add three lines to fieldToParameterMap:
`uid = tx_myext_pi1[question]
 theme = tx_myext_pi1[theme]
 tab = tx_myext_pi1[tab]`
As soon as all the three are declared, the sitemap looks as expected.